# Python C API segmentation fault when importing library in py file

Tags: python, c

I am trying to run a python program from a C program.

However when I add the line `import signal`  in my .py file I get a segmentation fault.

Using GDB I saw that the line `pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);` returns a NULL value.

```
(gdb) print pModule
$1 = (PyObject *) 0x0
```

When I remove the line `import signal` in python the module loads correctly.
Do you know how to fix this ?

Here is my python code:

```
import signal

def main(person):
    print("DANS PYTHON")
    return "What's up " + person;
```

And here is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>

void main(void) {
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject *pName,*pName2, *pModule, *pFunc, *pArgs, *pValue;
    PySys_SetPath(L".");    
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"main");                 
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);   
    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, (char*)"main");      
    pArgs = Py_BuildValue("(s)",(char *)"137912500"); 
    pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);                  
    Py_Finalize();                                               
    return;
}
```

I am working with Ubuntu 20.04

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: If the import statement fails, what's the point of the code underneath? Which code is actually the one failing? Please be precise with what you do and also extract a [mcve]. Also, you're not doing any error handling at all, which is questionable.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks you for your return, I edit my question to add more informations

Comment: `PySys_SetPath(L".")` - wait, what? Why are you setting `sys.path = ['.']`?

Comment: Hi, 

Without this line I thought my C program would not find my python script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 also and I have the same problem.

I found that the sys.path is `['.']` when run from a C program. So it search only in the current directory.

I was able to run your script by adding these 2 lines before `import signal`

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/lib/python3.8")

import signal

def main(person):
    print("DANS PYTHON")
    return "What's up " + person
```

To get the folder of the signal module I run :

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import signal
>>> signal.__file__
'/usr/lib/python3.8/signal.py'
>>>
```

I think that a configuration is missing somewhere but I have no clue about that.

Edit : you can also simply add the path in your C program:

```
PySys_SetPath(L".:/usr/lib/python3.8");
```

Comment: Thank you for these detailed explanations. By following your instructions my program works whether it's by modifying my python or C program.